# FactoryGirl assign attribute to aliase

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I write rspecs for Rails4 app and faced with issue in factory aliases

I have that factory:

```
factory :customer do
    name { "Name-#{rand(9999)}#{rand(9999)}#{rand(9999)}#{rand(9999)}" }
    billing_batch
    company
    end
end


factory :billing_batch do
    batch { "Default-#{rand(9999)}#{rand(9999)}#{rand(9999)}#{rand(9999)}" }
    company
end
```

If I create customer for particular company
`create(:customer, company: @company)` if will create billing_batch and assign it to customer (that part is correct), but also it create an extra company.

How can I specify in customer factory billing batch aliase company?

Comment: `@company` is AR or FB object?

Comment: use Sequences (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences)  instead of random numbers with fingers crossed hoping you'll be lucky and it's really unique

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
factory :customer do
    name { "Name-#{rand(9999)}#{rand(9999)}#{rand(9999)}#{rand(9999)}" }
    billing_batch
    company { billing_batch.company || build(:company) }
    end
end
```

I'm afk and can't test, but something like this should work.

Comment: I need sent company to billing_batch, not to customer

Comment: ah, Did you try `association :company` ?